# Cannot get Estimote Beacon to be seen using altbeacon android

Tags: android, bluetooth, altbeacon

i am trying to get and Estimote beacon to be seen by a sample app, but can't get it to work. I looked at these two samples and I can't see what I am doing differently than them since I copied most of the code.

References I am using:

https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

http://www.software7.com/blog/creating-a-beacon-app-for-android-in-less-than-10-minutes-from-scratch/

What bugs me is that I see these weird logs from my app, which seems like the bluetooth is not working for whatever reason.

I know the UUID is correct because I have another app installed that can see this exact same beacon with no issues, but when I tired to build my own app, I can't get it to work. The bluetooth is definitely on and wifi on or off does not matter.

I  wonder if anyone can spot the issue, since I have tried the code on HTC, Samsung Galaxy S6 and S5 (Lollipo and Marshmallow) and they all show the exact same logs.

logs from my app (that fails to see the beacon)

```
example.com.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25
example.com.beacontest D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24
example.com.beacontest D/Activity: performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
example.com.beacontest D/Activity: performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
example.com.beacontest W/BluetoothCrashResolver: Can't read macs from BluetoothCrashResolverState.txt
example.com.beacontest D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
example.com.beacontest D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=133 clientIf=0
example.com.beacontest I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@149c498c time:7966418897
example.com.beacontest I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@8067c9 time:7966418898
example.com.beacontest D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
example.com.beacontest D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
example.com.beacontest D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
example.com.beacontest D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=133 clientIf=0
example.com.beacontest D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
```

Here are the logs from the app that *** WORKS *** (using the same phones, beacon and OSes). Looks like is something I need to setup for the bluetooth on my app, but I don't really know what it is.

```
com.prodcode.dev D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
com.prodcode D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
com.prodcode D/BluetoothLeScanner: Stop Scan
com.prodcode D/BluetoothLeScanner: Start Scan
com.prodcode D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
com.prodcode D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
com.prodcode D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
com.prodcode D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
com.prodcode D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=13
```

thank you.

code of my sample app:

```
public class MonitoringActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BeaconConsumer {
    protected static final String TAG = "ESTIMOTE_BEACON";
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ranging);
        org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager altBeaconManager = org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        altBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
        altBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(5000);
        altBeaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(25000);
        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        BeaconManager.setAndroidLScanningDisabled(true);
        altBeaconManager.bind(this);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        beaconManager.unbind(this);
    }
    public static final int BEACON_REGION_MAX = 10;
    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        final String beaconID = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.beaconUUID).toUpperCase();
        final Region region = new Region("BEACON_TEST", Identifier.parse(beaconID), Identifier.fromInt(BEACON_REGION_MAX), null);
        beaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
                Log.d(TAG, "I just saw an beacon for the first time!");
                try {
                    beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
                Log.d(TAG, "I no longer see an beacon");
                try {
                    beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
                Log.d(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: " + state);
            }
        });

        beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "distance: " + beacon.getDistance() + " , " +
                            "id: " + beacon.getId1() + ", " +
                            "id: " + beacon.getId2() + ", " +
                            "id: " + beacon.getId3() + ", ");
                }
            }
        });
        try {
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my manifest and gradle:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

the gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories { jcenter() }
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.com.beacontest"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Do the app has required permissions? Go to settings->Apps-> Your app-> and check if the permission is granted. Am suggesting this because you are saying that you tried on Marshmallow but I cant see any code related to permissions.

Comment: I believe so. I added to the manifest and when I got to AppInfo, I see "access Bluetooth settings and pair with bluetooth devices"

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the app killed and stop scanning from beacons.

http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/resume-after-terminate.html

If I uninstall the app and re-install it works. Is there a better way to handle this?